# Multiple XML Parsing to Csv

Tags: xml, powershell, parsing

Have been trying to pull out certain data from multiple XML files into one csv file. Not much of a coder, but I have been able to play around with powershell and get some desired output, however the script only returns the first XML entry and stops. Please see XML input (all XMLs follow same input), code and desired output below, I have put my desired output below as well:

Input

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<Base Date='Update' Description='Test'>
 < name='Test'>
  <car>
   <cars CarID='45678901987612923'>
    <Information>
     <Info CarName='Audi' CarColour='Blue'/>
     <Info CarName='BMW' CarColour='Pink'/>
    </Information>
    <Owners>
     <Owner OwnerStatus='Current'>
      <OwnerInfo OwnerName='Joe Bloggs' OwnerAge='35'/>
     </OwnerInfo>
    </Owner>
                </Owners>
   </cars>
   <cars CarID='87654346789012678'>
    <Information>
     <Info CarName='Audi' CarColour='Yellow'/>
     <Info CarName='BMW' CarColour='Green'/>
    </Information>
    <Owners>
     <Owner OwnerStatus='Current'>
      <OwnerInfo OwnerName='Anne Smyth' OwnerAge='42'/>
     </OwnerInfo>
                    </Owner>
    </Owners>
   </cars>  
  </car>
    ...
    ...
    ...
   </name>
</Base>
```

Code

```html
$items = Get-ChildItem C:\*.xml
foreach ($item in $items) {[xml]$xml = (Get-Content $item)

$cars = $xml.Base.name.car.cars.Information.Info.CarColour

$owner = $xml.Base.name.car.cars.Owners.Owner.OwnerInfo.OwnerName
$results = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Audi= $cars[0]
BMW= $cars[1]
Owner= $owner[0]}
$results | Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append}
```

Output Currently

```html
Audi     BMW       Owner
Blue     Pink      Joe Bloggs
```

Desired Output

```html
Audi     BMW       Owner
Blue     Pink      Joe Bloggs
Yellow   Green     Anne Smyth
```

As mentioned above, the above works for multiple xmls of the same format, I just do not know how to populate it for each section of each XML, so I can get a full list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a bit convoluted, but it works. Perhaps an XML redesign would help things.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem C:\*.xml
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $item)
    $xml.base.name.car.cars | Foreach-Object {
        $results = [pscustomobject]@{
            'Audi' = $_.information.info.where{$_.CarName -eq 'Audi'}.CarColour
            'BMW' = $_.information.info.where{$_.CarName -eq 'BMW'}.Carcolour
            'Owner' = $_.Owners.Owner.OwnerInfo.OwnerName
        }
        $results | Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
     }
}
```

Since your common data points start at `$xml.base.name.car.cars` and that happens to be a collection, you can iterate the objects at that reference point. The `where` method helps filter the results. The member-access operator `.` can be used to access the `CarColour` property after a `where` condition is applied.

Comment: Perfect, appreciate the detailed explanation. Thanks!